# How can I upload multiple images using zod, react-hook-form?

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form, zod

## Background

I'm currently building a signup form with React18. I'm actively using react-hook-form and zod for form management.

## Problem

I want to allow the user to upload some attachments, but I'm not sure how to handle this in 'zod'.

Here's my code so far.

```
const submitSchema = z.object({
    // Applicant company/organization, required
    org_name: z.string().min(1, { message: "Please describe the applicant company/organization." }),


    // Status, optional
    status: z.enum(["public", "private"]),


    // Item picture, required
    images: z
        .array(z.instanceof(File))
        .refine(
            (files) => files.every((file) => file.size <= MAX_FILE_SIZE && ACCEPTED_IMAGE_TYPES.includes(file.type)),
            { }
                message: "Item photo: Only .jpeg, .jpg, .png files of 2MB or less are accepted",
            }
        ),
});
```

And this is `ImagesField` component.

```
type ImagesFieldProps = {
    className?: string;
};
const ImagesField = ({ className }: ImagesFieldProps) => {
    const { control } = useFormContext<SubmitSchemaType>();
    return (
        <FormField
            label={
                <div className="md:min-w-[150px]">
                    <BrowserView>
                        품목사진<div className="text-sm">(선택사항)</div>
                    </BrowserView>
                    <MobileView>품목사진 (선택사항)</MobileView>
                </div>
            }
            valueContent={
                <div className="file-input-set-container flex flex-col gap-3">
                    <Controller
                        name="images"
                        control={control}
                        render={({ field: { onChange, onBlur, name }, fieldState: { error } }) => (
                            <FileInput
                                name={name}
                                onChange={(e) => onChange([...(e.target.files ?? [])][0])}
                                onDelete={() => onChange(undefined)}
                                onBlur={onBlur}
                                errorMessages={error?.message}
                            />
                        )}
                    />
                    <Controller
                        name="images"
                        control={control}
                        render={({ field: { onChange, onBlur, name }, fieldState: { error } }) => (
                            <FileInput
                                name={name}
                                onChange={(e) => onChange([...(e.target.files ?? [])][0])}
                                onDelete={() => onChange(undefined)}
                                onBlur={onBlur}
                                errorMessages={error?.message}
                            />
                        )}
                    />
                </div>
            }
            className={className}
            noticeMessage="품목사진은 2M이하만 등록 가능합니다."
        />
    );
};
```

And I got this error message when submit.
`Expected array, received object`.

How to solve this problem and what is best practice to upload(validate) multiple images with zod and react-hook-form ?

Answer (score 2):

Probably the issue is that you are using two separate Controller components for the same field ("images"), which might be causing the error. Instead you can try using a single Controller and handle the array of files within that controller. You can add the multiple prop to the FileInput component to enable the selection of multiple files. Give something like this a try to see if it works,

```js
const ImagesField = ({ className }: ImagesFieldProps) => {
    const { control } = useFormContext<SubmitSchemaType>()
    
    return (
        <FormField
            label={
                <div className="md:min-w-[150px]">
                    <BrowserView>
                        품목사진<div className="text-sm">(선택사항)</div>
                    </BrowserView>
                    <MobileView>품목사진 (선택사항)</MobileView>
                </div>
            }
            valueContent={
                <div className="file-input-set-container flex flex-col gap-3">
                    <Controller
                        name="images"
                        control={control}
                        render={({ field: { onChange, onBlur, name }, fieldState: { error } }) => (
                            <FileInput
                                name={name}
                                onChange={(e) => onChange([...(e.target.files ?? [])])}
                                onBlur={onBlur}
                                errorMessages={error?.message}
                                multiple // Add this prop for multiple file selection
                            />
                        )}
                    />
                </div>
            }
            className={className}
            noticeMessage="품목사진은 2M이하만 등록 가능합니다."
        />
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem arises from the fact that the type="file" input returns a FileList object, which is essentially an array-like object containing File objects.

To fix this issue, you can ensure that the onChange event handler converts the FileList object into a proper array. You can achieve this by using Array.from() like so:

`onChange([...Array.from(e.target.files ?? [])])`